# Window Soft input mode for fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation

I have two fragments. First fragment is contain image and it is set in status bar as transparent with using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` Then I am opening Second Fragment using `transaction.add(R.id.main_fragment, fragment, tagName);`
In Second Fragment I have one editText at bottom of my screen. When I click on editText, keyboard open over control. I am using below code to make visibility of control.

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    }
```

But it is not working. If I set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in first fragment then it is working well. I don't want to **replace** fragment using fragment transaction. I checked with window mode SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN but using that my view goes in status bar. I also tried with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in second fragment at root view but it is not working.

Also I tried to change **fitsSystemWindows** programatically while I am changing fragment but it is not working. How can I resolve this issue?